# Bluetooth communication on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I need to write a Bluetooth application that communicates with Windows device using classic BT (since BLE is not available on Windows 7)

I found many BLE samples on iOS, but i couldn't find any classic BT code samples.

Can someone refer me to a code sample of how to use classic BT in iOS?

I am new to iOS development so any help would be good :)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851106/which-point-to-start-with-ble-technology-on-ios

Comment: @user3271633 Isn't is about BLE?

Answer (score 1):

To communicate to other devices via Bluetooth classic, you have to use [External Accessory Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html)

There is not so much info about it because it's all under strict NDA. You'll have to apply to [MFi](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) program to be able to use BT classic in your apps (the only exclusion is using GameKit framework, but it can be used only between iOS devices). It is not free and requires signing agreements with Apple.

Comment: What about what is written in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214023/how-to-use-bluetooth-classic-instead-of-le  it seems that I can't use it to communicate with windows

Comment: Well, all MFI-compliant accessories should have special MFi authentication chip. So you'll probably have to design some accessory that will connect to Windows device by wires and to iOS device by BT